# How to ssh to localhost without password?

Tags: networking, authentication, ssh, passwords, openssh

EDIT: Putting exactly what was done

I need to SSH localhost without password, the usual way of doing it (with public keys) do not work.

```
user@PC:~$ rm -rf .ssh/*
user@PC:~$ ssh-keygen -t rsa > /dev/null 
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
user@PC:~$ ls .ssh/
id_rsa  id_rsa.pub
user@PC:~$ ssh-copy-id -i localhost 
The authenticity of host 'localhost (::1)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is f7:87:b5:4e:31:a1:72:11:8e:5f:d2:61:bd:b3:40:1a.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
user@localhost's password: 
Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh 'localhost'", and check in:

  .ssh/authorized_keys

to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.

user@PC:~$ ssh-agent $SHELL
user@PC:~$ ssh-add -L
The agent has no identities.
user@PC:~$ ssh-add 
Identity added: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa)
user@PC:~$ ssh-add -L
ssh-rsa ...MY KEY HERE

user@PC:~$ ssh-copy-id -i localhost 
user@localhost's password: 
Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh 'localhost'", and check in:

  .ssh/authorized_keys

to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.

user@PC:~$ ssh localhost echo 'testing'
user@localhost's password: 

user@PC:~$
```

So as you can see in the last command it is still asking the password!
How can I fix that? Ubuntu-10.04, OpenSSH_5.3p1

EDIT2:

Adding some info about the sshd

```
user@PC:~$ cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep Authentication
# Authentication:
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
# PasswordAuthentication yes
```

EDIT3: Ading result from $ssh -vv localhost

```
$ssh -vv localhost
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@localhost's password:
```

Comment: Cross posted on Super User: https://superuser.com/questions/336226/how-to-ssh-to-localhost-without-password

Answer (score 196, accepted):

I did following 3 steps to create the password less login

```
1. ssh-keygen -t rsa
Press enter for each line 
2. cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
3. chmod og-wx ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: I could passwordless ssh without using step 3? When would I need to do step 3?

Comment: @Rich: that's just to protect against what [@shipr mentions in his answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10744443/98528). If your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` was already existing and had correct permissions, (3.) is not needed, but also does no harm.

Comment: in addition to appending `id_rsa.pub` to `authorized_keys` (which didn't exist before this on my *Mac*) I've also appended it to `known_hosts`. Still I'm being asked for *password*

Comment: OK I got it. For those who are perplexed (like me) because they already have a previously generated *rsa key pair*, just append the contents of the existing `id_rsa.pub` file to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (don't generate a new one). If the `authorized_keys` file doesn't exist, don't sweat, it will be automatically created (you probably knew that already) but more importantly appending it to `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file on `Mac` won't help. If you're using `ZSH` on `iTerm`, you would probably require restarting the *terminal*.

Comment: Works like a charm for macbook with macOS Mojave... +1

Comment: Does not work for me. Password is still required when logging in `ssh localhost`

Comment: using ubuntu 22.04 faced this issue. after 3rd cmd ssh working fine

Comment: all I had to do was ssh-copy-id localhost and it worked

Answer (score 21):

Have discovered the problem.

Running the server with debuging:

```
$sshd -Dd
```

I found it was not able to read the auth_key

```
$chmod 750 $HOME
```

Fixed it.

Comment: Why don't you guys use symbolic chmod mode? It is not 90's any more, is it?

Comment: Because symbolic mode is confusing. I have no idea what 750 would be off the top of my head. something like 'u=rwx,g=rx,o=' Whatever it is, it's not easier than 750! Btw, 755 perms work just fine as well.

Comment: Very useful. I used `/usr/sbin/sshd -ddddD` and got the following message `Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/...`

Comment: found it was this as well. Thankyou :)
Home directory fixed it. Had similar debug messages about bad ownership. I would see the debug log after I ran `ssh -v localhost`. error was `bad ownership or modes for directory $HOME`. I had done the steps above from other uses before.

Answer (score 21):

Another *possible* answer: the authorized_keys file may exist and be readable.  But if it is group- or world-writable, it will still prompt for the password.  The answer to THAT problem is

```
chmod og-wx ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 10):

Two simple steps:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa <Press enter for each line>
ssh-copy-id localhost
```

Enter password and you're done.

Answer (score 6):

Do the following steps

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
# Creates a new ssh key, using the provided email as a label
# Generating public/private rsa key pair.
```

Use the default file and empty passphrase (Simply press enter in the next 2 steps)

```
# start the ssh-agent in the background
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
# Agent pid 59566
ssh-add
```

Copy the contents of ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Ensure following are the permissions

```
 ls -l .ssh/
 total 20
-rw-r--r--. 1 swati swati  399 May  5 14:53 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r--. 1 swati swati  761 Jan 12 15:59 config
-rw-------. 1 swati swati 1671 Jan 12 15:44 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--. 1 swati swati  399 Jan 12 15:44 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--. 1 swati swati  410 Jan 12 15:46 known_hosts
```

Also, ensure the permissions for .ssh directory are. This is also important

```
drwx------.   2 swati swati    4096 May  5 14:56 .ssh
```

Answer (score 2):

On Centos 7

SOLUTION

```
1 create rsa key
2 vim /etc/ssh/ssh_config
3
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
uncoment this line > IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
```

Note *I did this after copying the key and some of the other answers before this one. But I am pretty sure this is all you have to do but if not I would append the rsa key to authorized_keys and also run the

ssh-copy-id to username@localhost

Answer (score 1):

The correct and safe way of doing it is to copy the keys as has been said here.

In other cases, `sshpass` can be handy.

```
sshpass -p raspberry ssh pi@192.168.0.145
```

Keep in mind that this is not safe at all. Even though it is not a good idea to use it in secure environments, it can be useful for scripting, automated testing...

this can be combined with

```
ssh -q -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no pi@192.168.0.145
```

to avoid confirmation questions that prevent scripting from happening.

Again, only use this in development systems where different machines share an IP and security is not important.

https://ownyourbits.com/2017/02/22/easy-passwordless-ssh-with-sshh/

Answer (score 1):

as the accepted answer do,
if you encount a problem of

```
    Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
```

you need to

```
    ssh-add
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue even after following all the recommendations, but found out that the issue was with gnome-keyring interference.

Solution:

1. Go Search , look for “Startup Applications”
2. If you see “SSH Key Agent”, uncheck the box
3. Reboot the machine and connect to localhost.

Answer (score 1):

I solved ssh login problem this way.

I generate the key pairs on my server side and then scp back the private key to my windows 10 computer and now I can login without password.

Previously I used key pairs generated by my window 10 laptop and there was no luck at all.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem when running unit tests on Docker container(golang:1.13-alpine).

After `sshd -Dd` and `ssh -vv root@localhost` debugging, I found the reason:

> User root not allowed because account is locked

So, we should unlock the account by `passwd -u` 
or set a password.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to doublecheck if you have a known good configuration for ssh is that your /etc/hosts.allow includes a reference to localhost, since the source IP for a localhost connection would be coming from 127.0.0.1 rather than your network IP. I was stumped on this for some time, but after adding the following to /etc/hosts.allow my configuration immediately worked.

```
ALL: 127.0.0.1/32
```

I figured I would add this since none of the other answers mentioned it and this was the top hit from my search for the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem setting the AllowUsers on sshd_config file.

Running the server with debuging:

$sshd -Dd

I found it was not allowed the my user

$sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Add a row with after #Authentication:

AllowUsers myUser

Answer (score 0):

**RHEL8**

In my case after successful keys configuration it still did not work. I found following error in /var/log/secure:

```
pam_access(sshd:account): access denied for user `username' from `::1'
```

So I had to edit:

```
/etc/security/access.conf
```

And add there '::1' to allowed hosts by adding a line:

```
+:<username>:LOCAL ::1
```

It immediately started to work, even without restart of **sshd** service.