# Permission error occured while executing yardstick-ignite framework

Tags: java, frameworks, benchmarking, ignite

Why is this console statement printed multiple times while running `yardStick-ignite` framework example?

If i've made a mistake can you please show me how to run the `yardStick-ignite` framework example?

```
<16:56:46><yardstick> Starting driver config '...-cn query -sn IgniteNode -ds Ignite-sql-query-put-1-backup' on localhost
Permission denied (publickey,password).
Permission denied (publickey,password).
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Run steps:
1) Create clone of git-hub library (git clone https://github.com/yardstick-benchmarks/yardstick-ignite)
2) Use (mvn package) command to compile the project and also to unpack scripts
3) Change Ip of driver and server from benchmark.properties
4) Run this command ./benchmark-run-all.sh

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure ssh access to localhost without password. Refer to instruction there : [How to ssh to localhost without password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439563/how-to-ssh-to-localhost-without-password)

BTW this repository contains benchmarks for old Apache Ignite and yardstick version. New version of yardstick doesn't have this limitation and new version of Apache Ignite provide the better performance. In the last versions Apache Ignite distributed with benchmarks. You can download there https://ignite.apache.org/download.cgi#binaries and found them and instruction in /benchmarks folder.